# Call to a member function execute() on a non-object in

Tags: php, mysql, session

I have the following error, and this is the exact same form processing file I use for registering a user, but I changed it for the appropriate table and columns. While the reg works fine every time. 
Here is the code where the error is located:

```html
$sql = "INSERT INTO events1 (eventname,about,website) VALUES (:yas,:yasas,:yasasha)";
$q = $conn->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array(':yas'=>$eventname,':yasas'=>$about,':yasasha'=>$website));
```

Here is the full code:

```html
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "Af2vaz93j68";
$dbname = "pdo_ret";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
$eventname = $_POST['eventname'];
$about = $_POST['about'];
$website = $_POST['website'];


if($eventname == '') {
  $errmsg_arr[] = 'You must enter your Email';
  $errflag = true;
}
if($about == '') {
  $errmsg_arr[] = 'You must enter your Password';
  $errflag = true;
}
if($website == '') {
  $errmsg_arr[] = 'You must enter First Name';
  $errflag = true;
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO events1 (eventname,about,website) VALUES (:yas,:yasas,:yasasha)";
$q = $conn->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array(':yas'=>$eventname,':yasas'=>$about,':yasasha'=>$website));
 


if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: Did you checked if the connection failed? Also please show us your **full** code. So if there are other errors we see it right away. (Add error reporting at the top of your file(s): `<?php
  ini_set("display_errors", 1);
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ?>` And tell us if you get any more errors.

Comment: Yep the connection is fine. I'll update the code

Comment: What is the error message? Maybe some column is required but you are tying to save an empty string?

Comment: You have to check if all values are sent if you want to run a query...$eventame,$about and $website could be empty at the time you run query.

Comment: member function execute() on a non-object in line 33:
Line 33 is: $q->execute(array(':yas'=>$eventname,':yasas'=>$about,':yasasha'=>$website));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Youre confusing `PDO` and mysqli. `mysqli` does not support named parameters so you stmt is not compiling and `Mysqli::prepare` is returning false. Additionally mysqli does not support passing the param to be bound through `mysqli_stmt::execute` so even if you switch to positional placeholders your execute will fail.

This is what you would need for mysqli:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO events1 (eventname,about,website) VALUES (?,?,?)";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

// check to make sure the statement was prepared without error
if ($stmt) {
   // the statement is good - proceed
   $stmt->bind_param('sss', $eventname, $about, $website);
   $stmt->execute();
}
```

Additionally this makes no sense at all:

```
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
```

This will just run the same query again either inserting a second row of the exact same data, or perhaps creating a duplicate key error depending upon your schema.

If you want to test that the previous query succeeded you would do something like:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO events1 (eventname,about,website) VALUES (?,?,?)";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

if ($stmt) {
    $stmt->bind_param('sss', $eventname, $about, $website);
    $success = $stmt->execute();
} else {
    $success = false;
}

if ($success === true) {
     echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
```

If you want to use PDO (which i prefer and usually recommend) your code would look something like this:

```
$conn = PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);


try {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO events1 (eventname,about,website) VALUES (:yas,:yasas,:yasasha)";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute(array(':yas'=>$eventname,':yasas'=>$about,':yasasha'=>$website));
    echo "New record created successfully";
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: How could I fix this? I've been told by my friend that I still am getting confused with PDO and mysqli. What about 
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname",$dbuser,$dbpass);

Comment: @SARUAV I added PDO example code if you wanna switch. Really you just need to pick one. I prefer PDO myself, but as long as you are consistent it should be fine.

Comment: Thank you, I'll take note of that, and I think I will go with PDO now :)

Comment: I just copied the same code which works on events1
Created a new one for groups, all the colombs are the same, just the table name needed changing. And I get this error again.
Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in

Comment: There could be any number of things wrong with your SQL. when `mysqli::prepare` fails it returns `false`, so if you get that error from `bind_param` that failed to create the prepared statement. You can check `$conn->error` (ie. `Mysqli::error` to get the last error. It should give you info about what went wrong. Also, you previously stated you were going to switch to PDO so make sure you arent mixing the API's as they are different even though some of the methods seem similar.

Comment: I just added some error checking to the `mysqli` examples.